# Is there such a thing as a iPad stylus with a (relatively) fine and hard nib?

Tags: ipad, stylus

I use the [Griffin stylus](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/stylus) and although it does the job well enough it's a long way removed from using a pen on a tablet - I find the soft nib makes it difficult to write accurately. The other pens I've seen all seem to have a similar design - presumably to make the nib appear to the iPad as a finger.

I understand pressure sensitivity isn't going to be an option but a relatively hard nib would make it a lot easier to 'write' on the iPad.

Comment: After a little further investigation it appears that there is another _type_ of stylus starting to come out. There is the [iPen](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1225098940/ipen-the-first-active-stylus-for-ipad) due for release Jan 2012 and several [similar offerings](http://www.theverge.com/2011/12/28/2665456/cregle-ipen-active-digitizer-stylus-kickstarter). More expensive but much more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Thoroughly recommend the Cosmonaut:
http://www.studioneat.com/products/cosmonaut

Still a relatively soft nib but the size of the stylus nib seems to reduce the squidgy resistance I've experienced with smaller stylus. Also the chunkyness of the Cosmonaut grip feels great in the hand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Cosmonaut does look pretty much the same as the one I'm using already. Nice design though.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Jot](http://adonit.net/) and the [XStylus Touch](http://www.indiegogo.com/XStylus-Touch). I already have an XStylus on order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The XStylus Touch looks like the some kind of squidgy nib. The Jot looks like an interesting development that adds a little refinement to the technology.